# Python3.11 install pyvsc package

Tags: python, python-3.11

I install the latest version "pyvsc" module in python3.11.4, but it throws error `/tmp/pip-install-vhqnf19u/CMakeLists.txt` can not found, just as shown below：

```bash
25 [root@rd1 17:36 ~/pyvsc]# pip3  install -e .
Obtaining file:///root/pyvsc
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Checking if build backend supports build_editable ... done
  Getting requirements to build editable ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing editable metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting pyboolector>=3.2.2 (from pyvsc==0.8.3)
  Using cached PyBoolector-3.2.2.20230110.4.tar.gz (21 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [21 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/data/tools/python/3.11.4/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/data/tools/python/3.11.4/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/data/tools/python/3.11.4/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-f14tfzkv/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-f14tfzkv/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-f14tfzkv/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 488, in run_setup
          self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-f14tfzkv/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
      FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-install-vhqnf19u/CMakeLists.txt'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
```

Comment: It looks like you're installing from source.  Did you try just installing from pypi.org with `pip install pyvsc` or `python -m pip install pyvsc`?

Comment: I try use `pip3 install pyvsc`, but it alse throw above error.

I find it don't throw error when I user python3.10 or python3.7,  but I must use python3.11

Comment: I try install `CMake-3.27.2`,  then install `pyvsc`, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: There's a [documented issue](https://github.com/fvutils/pyvsc/issues/171) on GitHub reporting the same problem.  The PyBoolector package doesn't have pre-built libraries for Windows, and it depends on the mingw/msys compiler for Windows, but pre-built binary packages require that the VS compiler be used.  You could try manually installing PyBoolector on its own by its directions first.  There is also a [linked issue for PyBoolector](https://github.com/Boolector/boolector/issues/175) that just says to make sure pip has been updated with `pip install --upgrade pip`